# Filter DynamoDB stream events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am trying to filter DynamoDB stream events before invoking lambda function:
`completed` - boolean field, accepting anything except `true` value.
Using terraform filter_criteria:

```hcl
filter_criteria {
    filter {
      pattern = jsonencode({
        dynamodb = { 
          "NewImage": { 
            "completed": { "BOOL": [{ "anything-but": [ true ] } ] } 
          } 
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Getting:

> Error: error updating Lambda Event Source Mapping (8373b67a-e905-4d61-b082-c43ba843c3a3): InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid filter pattern definition.

Can anyone spot what's the issue?

Comment: If you drop the square brackets around `true`, what happens? I.e., if that line becomes: `"completed": { "BOOL": [{ "anything-but": true } ] }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "true" instead of true

```
filter_criteria {
    filter {
      pattern = jsonencode({
        dynamodb = { 
          "NewImage": { 
            "completed": { "BOOL": [{ "anything-but": [ "true" ] } ] } 
          } 
        }
      })
    }
  }
```